# why I am getting this exception?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

### eb 19, 2018 11:45:47 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.13.Final} Feb 19, 2018 11:45:47 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found Feb 19, 2018 11:45:47 AM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead. Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time. Feb 19, 2018 11:45:48 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager  INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found : hibernate_test.Emp_Info.hibernate.hbm.xml : origin(hibernate_test.Emp_Info.hibernate.hbm.xml) at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.bind(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:56) at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.addResource(MetadataSources.java:274) at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.spi.MappingReference.apply(MappingReference.java:70) at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:413) at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87) at `enter code here`org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726) at hibernate_test.Hibernate_Test.main(Hibernate_Test.java:23)

Comment: I think you have hibernate jar version problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it is clear that you have missing items in your hibernate configuration. Could you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve?